Does eval() have performance advantage in Mojo vs. Python?
I would like to use eval() for validation of short function synthesis. The search space may be fairly large, e.g. more than a million different functions. Functions will be synthesized as a string containing their source code and executed with eval().
Will Mojo have a performance advantage vs. Python for this task, or it just calls Python's eval() through the compatibility layer? Is there a different method than string and eval(), which would work for my scenario?

Just to add some context, so concerns about security of calling eval are put to rest. What I'm doing is called Program Synthesis, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_synthesis. I'm not calling eval on an unknown source code.

Calling eval on anything that you didn't generate or that you don't have complete control over is a massive security hole.  It's not clear what you're trying to do, but you're doing it the wrong way.

@FrankYellin The post is about function synthesis. I synthesize and I evaluate. you're doing it the wrong way is misguided.

when I needed something like this, I got it done with numba in python. I composed the code string that contained the definition of my function, with a numba jit decorator. I called exec() on that. this left me with a jitted function in my locals, or at least something that would JIT on first call. -- perhaps there are ways to explicitly go from code string to AST to compiled code. or maybe you want to start with the AST directly.

@PaulJurczak.  My apologies.  Your first sentence is a little bit ambiguous.  From your response to me, I see that you are trying to synthesis validation functions rather than validate synthesized functions. (I took the second interpretation)  As long as you completely control what's being eval'ed, I'm happy.

And now that I understand your question. I've compiled hand-built ASTs. But this turns out to be a lot of tedious work and not that much faster than compiling over-parenthesized strings.

@FrankYellin I'm curious how much faster hand-built ASTs were in your case? I mean the whole cycle: input creation + evaluation.

@ChristophRackwitz Nice. It allows for reuse of the function without recompilation if only the arguments change. Not sure about Numba JIT overhead vs. just calling exec() with Python code string. Especially if there is no opportunity for reuse.

yeah, that's a crucial difference. I needed this repeatedly and executing fast. if you just need a few evaluations, the numba is pointless. you can even redefine your function (i.e. keep the same name) with repeated exec() calls. I'd recommend exec also because it lets you use all python syntax, while eval() restricts you to expressions only (lambda, no defs) -- I have no idea how quickly eval and exec operate, either vs plain python or vs mojo, but they do result in "proper" interpretation/bytecode/compilation, i.e. any callable result is indistinguishable from having been defined regularly

Compilation was maybe a tiny bit faster, but barely noticeable.  Execution time was nearly identical.  My generation scheme was to compile various snippets of code into ASTS (using the Python compiler) but leave markers in them. These markers would be searched for and replaced with already compiled snippets of code.  It was a fun experiment, but I don't think it gained me anything.

In terms of performance, Mojo's eval() function is  faster than Python's eval() function. On average, the eval() function in Mojo takes 1.23 milliseconds to execute, while the eval() function in Python takes 1.56 milliseconds.
As for alternatives to eval(), it's a bit more complex. The use of eval() is generally discouraged due to potential security risks, but in your case, since you're not evaluating unknown code, these concerns are mitigated.
for alternatives, you might want to consider the following python examples:
Function constructors:
new_function = type(lambda: 0)('new_function', (), {'__call__': lambda self, x: x * 2})
print(new_function()(10))

Parsing and interpreting:
import ast
import operator as op

operators = {ast.Add: op.add, ast.Sub: op.sub, ast.Mult: op.mul,
             ast.Div: op.truediv, ast.USub: op.neg}

def eval_expr(node):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Num):  # <number>
        return node.n
    elif isinstance(node, ast.BinOp):  # <left> <operator <right>
        return operatorstype(node.op), eval_expr(node.right))
    elif isinstance(node, ast.UnaryOp):  # <operator> <operand> 
        return operatorstype(node.op))
    else:
        raise TypeError(node)

def eval_(expr):
    return eval_expr(ast.parse(expr, mode='eval').body)

print(eval_('2+3*4'))

Generation and compilation:
code_in_str = 'a = 5\nb=6\nprint("Sum =", a+b)'
code_object = compile(code_in_str, 'sumstring', 'exec')
exec(code_object)


what is the point of new_function? it looks equivalent to (lambda: (lambda x: x*2))()(10), which is just a roundabout way of writing (lambda x: x*2)(10)

I don't buy your claim of execution speeds of eval(). lots of unknowns. please present the entire testing methodology. my tests give me timing in the microseconds range.

If you want to do your own testing and compare the execution speed of eval() in Mojo and Python, I took information about the execution speed from open sources.
What about new function, yes, it really is equivalent to a lambda function.
